Scully not setting up the necessary config files for Angular 17
I am trying to create a brand new demo project with Scully. I have created a home module, manually added app.module.ts as well as app-routing.module.ts. However, when running the commands from the documentation, the package doesnt generate the required files. Following the manual installation also doesnt help much:

ng add @scullyio/init didnt generate a scully..config.ts although packages have been added.

Anybody has a solution?

With all due respects to the maintainers of scully, the project seems pretty dead.  The last production release was 2 years ago.  I switched over to using Angular's SSR, and while Scully was a bit more forgiving and had features I miss (sitemap plugin!), Angular's has worked well.  Also consider Astro Angular if this is a new project and you're creating a lot of static content.
